# Run Cefsharp as Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, whatsapp, cefsharp

Is it possible to use CefSharp as 'Chrome'? I know, it is a kind of Chrome, but webpages doesn't see CefSharp as Chrome.
The story:
I want to embed WhatsApp Web with CefSharp, but Whatsapp says: Only Chrome supported. Are there any possibilities to 'fake' Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WhatsApp Web checks for browser capabilities. It fails when checking for navigator.getUserMedia. To enable WebRTC audio/video you need to set the `--enable-media-stream` flag. Set it programmatically through the `CefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs` option. For an example  see [CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/572f2bfc7047e41da2c1229a19635e12b279dd66/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L29).